# Ruby variable from string variable concatanation

Tags: ruby

I am learning ruby and wondering if it is possible to create a var from a variable combined with a string.

```
a = "variable"
a+"_name" = []
variable_name => []
```

Thanks,
CG

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this easily with an instance variable as such:

```
>> a = "variable"
=> "variable"
>> instance_variable_set(:"@#{a}_name", [])
=> []
>> @variable_name
=> []
```

If you're curious about why this is easier to do with an ivar, read up about Ruby variable binding and scoping rules.

Comment: What is the # doing in this @#{a}_name and is the : setting it as a symbol?

Comment: @CoryGwin: The leading `:` makes it a symbol, the `#{}` inside the double quoted string is just normal string interpolation.

Answer (score 3):

But don't do that. So much easier and better to use a hash:

```
variable = {}
variable['name'] = []
```

or

```
vars = {}
vars[["variable", "name"]] = []
```

Comment: Yeah hash is strongly recommended when comes to undelcared var or methods. It can take care of it

Comment: I take it this is for name spacing? What if it is part of a class, or I guess object instance?

Comment: THis question has been asked before, and I have yet to see a good reason to do it.   Php had some sort of variable interpolation, and I suspect most of the questions like this are people bringing that abomination into ruby... ;)

Answer (score 1):

Incase you still want to do with variables:

```
>> a = 'variable'
 => "variable" 
>> eval(a + '_name=[]')
 => [] 
>> variable_name
 => []
```

Hope you understand how evil eval is!